# Drive entity no longer returns a driveType attribute

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I'm observing a change in functionality in Microsoft Graph. When requesting a list of `drives` from a SharePoint site, I used to see a `driveItem` attribute that no longer seems to be present as of Nov 14.

The [`site` documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/site) mentions the relationship to the `drives` collection.

The [`drive` documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/drive) describes the `driveType` attribute as:

> Describes the type of drive represented by this resource. OneDrive personal drives will return `personal`. OneDrive for Business will return `business`. SharePoint document libraries will return `documentLibrary`. Read-only.

Here is an example call:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/drives
```

Response:

```http
client-request-id →d822c749-baf6-4857-abd9-6d80f70823d9
request-id →d822c749-baf6-4857-abd9-6d80f70823d9
x-ms-ags-diagnostic →{"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"EastUS","Slice":"SliceB","Ring":"NA","ScaleUnit":"003","Host":"AGSFE_IN_28","ADSiteName":"EST"}}

{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#drives",
    "value": [
        {
            "createdBy": {
                "user": {
                    "displayName": "System Account"
                }
            },
            "createdDateTime": "2015-05-22T17:21:01Z",
            "description": "This system library was created by the PointPublishing feature to store application pages.",
            "id": "b!a4YqXM4QKkOPmOj73xfdss5bbYPr7MlFlXKVhtK0Dpjf4OJPyoBFQo2-YK5095t1",
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2015-05-22T17:21:03Z",
            "name": "AppPages",
            "webUrl": "https://mysharepoint.sharepoint.com/portals/hub/AppPages",
            "quota": {
                "deleted": 0,
                "remaining": 0,
                "total": 0,
                "used": 0
            }
        }
      <snipped a few values>
    ]
}
```

Is the change in functionality I am seeing here by design or non-intended?

Edit:   When attempting the call:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/drives?$select=id,driveType,Name
```

The `driveType` is returned

```json
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#drives(id,driveType,name)",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "fakeId",
            "name": "Documents",
            "driveType": "documentLibrary"
        }
    ]
}
```

When requesting `drives` for a site based on the `site-id` (`/sites/{site-id}/drives`) we see different attributes returned.

Comment: I am seeing the `driveType` property returned correctly. Could you check `/v1.0/sites/root/drives?$select=id,driveType,Name` and post those results?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur :  I added the above query, it still does not return driveTypes.    {
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#drives(id,driveType,name)",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "b!a4YqXM4QKkOPmOj73xfdss5bbYPr7MlFlXKVhtK0Dpjf4OJPyoBFQo2-YK5095t1",
            "name": "AppPages"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: I'm not seeing the results. Are you sure you saved your edit? (note that my URI is _not_ the same as the URI you originally posted)

Comment: @MarcLaFleur  - I missed the different URI.   Edited the original post to include those results.

Comment: I've actually just run across a second example of this. It certainly seems like a behavior specific to a given SP site. I'm not sure yet what determines why it shows up in some places but not others. Looking into it now.

Comment: This is a regression and a fix is being pushed as we speak.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

Just closing the loop on this. As Brad mentioned, an issue has been identified. A fix is currently in the pipeline and should be rolling out soon.